# how to retrieve the largest value from a map in pig

Tags: hadoop, dictionary, apache-pig

I have a relation. describe books -> {map[]}.

here one of the pairs, key is Ashok LeyLand and value is Ashok 0.15

```
Ashok LeyLand#Ashok 0.15.
Ashok LeyLand#Land 0.012.
Ashok LeyLand#Ley 0.002.
Ashok LeyLand#Ashoka 0.09.
Hero Cycles Limited#Hero Cycles 0.72
Hero Cycles Limited#Hero 0.06
Hero Cycles Limited#Hero Limited 0.54
Hero Cycles Limited#Cycles 0.01
```

I want the pair with highest value. Need output as Ashok LeyLand#Ashok 0.15. 
I can modify the relation to below if there's a possibility to get the desired output.

here one of the pairs, key is Ashok LeyLand Ashok value is 0.15

```
Ashok LeyLand Ashok#0.15.
Ashok LeyLand Land#0.012.
Ashok LeyLand Ley#0.002.
Ashok LeyLand Ashoka#0.09.
Hero Cycles Limited Hero Cycles#0.72
Hero Cycles Limited Hero#0.06
Hero Cycles Limited Hero Limited#0.54
Hero Cycles Limited Cycles#0.01
```

Thanks

Comment: have you tried using MapToBag UDF to transform your map to bag and then order the tuples inside bag?

Comment: I am new to piglatin, can u please elaborate?

Comment: You can not order values of Map. You can order the tuples inside a bag. Use MapToBag UDF to transform your Map (key#value) to a bag {(key, value)} and then use ORDER operation to order the tuples in the bag by value.

Comment: I think we don't have MapToBag in piggybank. can you share? 
And after ordering the tuples we get ordered list right? But I only need the pair with high score.
eg., 1.Ashok LeyLand#Ashok 0.15
     2.Hero Cycles Limited Hero Cycles#0.72 and so on..

Comment: Yes, its not in piggybank. I think I used it from some personal library. You might want to define your own UDF. About using ORDER, once you order the tuples, you can use limit to select 1st tuple (which would be highest value)

Comment: Thanks Gaurav for asking me to use UDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I transformed map into bag using MapToBag UDF. Grouped the rows by the required key using GROUP. Used Top function to filter the highest instead of using ORDER BY AND LIMIT.

Comment: great. would you mind pasting your code here? This will help other folks with the same question.